# Why is my Either-returning method always returning Left, irrespective of what happened?

Tags: c#, functional-programming, language-ext

The use case here is that I have added a method to an Entity Framework `DbContext` that does some extra work before saving, and then returns an `Either` depending on the results. A very simplified version of this looks like this...

```cs
static async Task<Either<string, Unit>> SaveChangesAsyncEither(string userId) {
  // In reality, this would do some auditing, check for concurrency issues, and
  // attempt to save the changes. It would return unit if all went OK, 
  // or an error message if not. Simple check for demonstrating the issue...
  if (userId == "jim") {
    return "We don't like Jim";
  }
  return unit;
}
```

This method is used in many places in my solution, and wors fine.

In one minimal API project, I have a method that looks like this (again, highly simplified)...

```cs
static async Task<Either<DeviceApiResponseStates, DeviceApiResponseStates>> CreateDevice(string userId) {
  // In reality we would have more parameters, create a device, etc before
  // calling SaveChangesAsyncEither
  return (await SaveChangesAsyncEither(userId))
      .Match(() => Right<DeviceApiResponseStates, DeviceApiResponseStates>(DeviceApiResponseStates.OK),
        _ => Left(DeviceApiResponseStates.Nah));
}
```

...where `DeviceApiResponseStates` is an `enum`. For simplicity, you can imagine it looks like this...

```cs
enum DeviceApiResponseStates {
  OK,
  Nah
}
```

Those three code blocks are a complete sample of my problem.

I would expect that if I call `CreateDevice("jim")`, then I would get a `Left` with a value of `Nah`, and if I call it with any other string value, I would get a `Right` with a value of OK.

However, when I try this...

```cs
Console.WriteLine((await CreateDevice(""))
  .Match(_ => "Yeah", ex => $"Exception: {ex}"));
```

... I get Nah, irrespective of the string value.

Anyone able to explain what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @MarkSeemann I managed to reduce the problem down to a surprisingly small sample which reproduces the issue. Please can you have a look and see what you think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TL;DR: Three-keystroke edit:

```
static async Task<Either<DeviceApiResponseStates, DeviceApiResponseStates>> CreateDevice(string userId)
{
    // In reality we would have more parameters, create a device, etc before
    // calling SaveChangesAsyncEither
    return (await SaveChangesAsyncEither(userId))
        .Match(_ => Right<DeviceApiResponseStates, DeviceApiResponseStates>(DeviceApiResponseStates.OK),
            _ => Left(DeviceApiResponseStates.Nah));
}
```

Notice that I've changed the input argument in the first `Match` argument from `()` to `_`.

## ...but why?!

Indeed, this took me some time figuring out.

It may be important to state the following up-front, since I don't know if you're familiar with other functional languages - especially F#, but also Haskell:

In C#, the lambda expression `() => x` has the type `Func<T>`, not `Func<Unit, T>`. (F# is more elegant, because `fun () -> x` *does* indicate a function `unit -> 'a`, because in F#, `()` has the type `unit`. Not so in C#, where 'no data' as input in a lambda expression has the special syntax `() =>`, and as output has the special keyword `void`. So, just to belabour the point, a C# lambda expression `x => {}` has the type `Action<T>`, whereas in F# `fun x -> ()` would have the type `'a -> unit`.

All this means that when you write `.Match(() => ...` the C# compiler interprets that lambda expression as a `Func<Either<DeviceApiResponseStates, DeviceApiResponseStates>>`, that is, a function that takes no input. The C# overload resolver goes looking for a method or extension method that takes a `Func<T>` (*not* a `Func<Unit, T>)` as input, and finds this one:

```
public static B Match<A, B>(this IEnumerable<A> list, Func<B> Empty, Func<Seq<A>, B> More)
{
    return Prelude.toSeq(list).Match(Empty, More);
}
```

in LanguageExt's `ListExtensions`. Notice the `Func<B> Empty` parameter.

This is an extension method on `IEnumerable<T>` rather than `Either<L, R>`. Why does this compile?

Well, it compiles because `Either<L, R>` implements `IEnumerable<T>`:

```
public readonly struct Either<L, R> : IEnumerable<EitherData<L, R>>, IEnumerable, ...
```

By using `_` instead of `()`, you tell the compiler that you expect *some* value as input to your lambda expression, instead of no input. It just so happens that the input you expect is a/the `Unit` value.

This now excludes the `IEnumerable<T>` extension method, and instead enables the compiler to locate the correct `Match` method on `Either<L, R>`.

Comment: Wow, I don't think I would ever have figured that out on my own! Thanks so much for the explanation. I have enough knowledge of F# to understand what you mean, although not much of Haskell, much to my shame, I'd love to learn it, but lack of time and brain!